How does Layer-2 transactions propagate to centralized sequencer?
I was checking the block production steps for Optimism/Base and this source

https://docs.optimism.io/stack/protocol/rollup/overview#block-production

has mentioned this:
Transactions submitted directly to the sequencer. These transactions are a lot cheaper to submit, as they do not require the expense of a separate L1 transaction.

If I understand correctly, it means that Optimism sequencer will be receiving the user transaction through eth_sendRawTransaction  at https://mainnet-sequencer.optimism.io, which is the sequencer URL according to https://docs.optimism.io/chain/networks#op-mainnet.
However, how come other third party provider also provides such endpoint?
Taking Quicknode for example, they also offer eth_sendRawTransaction on https://www.quicknode.com/docs/optimism/eth_sendRawTransaction
But iirc, Optimism only has one centralized sequencer that is hold by the Optimism foundation itself.
So the question is, who will be receiving the transactions on Layer2 and how does it propagates to the centralized sequencer?
Thanks!

According to this flow:

The verifier will gossip transaction received directly to the sequencer.
So basically any roles inside the op network can receive raw transactions and they will all get forwarded to the centralized sequencer in the end.
source: https://tianpan.co/notes/288-how-does-optimism-work#op-proposer
